# sed with parens in seach not working

Tags: sed, regex

I need to replace
`DatabaseConnection.GetConnection()`
with
`DatabaseConnection.GetConnection(_connectionString)`

Using grep (GNU grep) 3.1

```
grep GetConnection() CustomerRepository.cs
```

yields

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

however

```
grep GetConnection\(\) CustomerRepository.cs`
```

outputs

```
using (IDbConnection connection = DatabaseConnection.GetConnection())
```

as expected

Using sed (GNU sed) 4.8

```
sed -e 's/GetConnection()/GetConnection(_connectionString)/' CustomerRepository.cs
```

outputs the entire contents of the input file, as it does when I escape the search parentheses.

Totally lost, what do I need to do to have this work?

Comment: Well `sed` and `grep` have different purposes - what is it that you **want** to do?

Comment: Replace `DatabaseConnection.GetConnection() ` with `DatabaseConnection.GetConnection(_connectionString)`

Comment: Add `_connectionString` parameter between the parentheses.

Comment: Well your sed command should do that: there's no need to escape the parentheses - unlike in your `grep` command, they're protected from the shell by the single quotes, and sed's default regular expression dialect is BRE in which parentheses are not special (you **would** need to escape the ones on the LHS if you'd used sed's `-E` or `-r` options to change the dialect to ERE)

Comment: `sed -e 's/GetConnection\(\)/GetConnection(_connectionString)/' CustomerRepository.cs` displays the entire contents of the input file, as do `sed -E..` and `sed -r...`.

Comment: `sed` will display all lines (both changed and unchanged) unless you add the `-n` or `--quiet` option

Answer (score 0):

"grep GetConnection() CustomerRepository.cs"

is right to complain, as "(" is specially interpreted by the shell and doesn't make sense the way you use it.

Escaping "(" as "(" and ")" as ")" is a good thing to do, but putting the whole argument into quotes would be even better:

```
grep 'GetConnection()' CustomerRepository.cs
```

As for your second try,

```
sed -e 's/GetConnection()/GetConnection(_connectionString)/' CustomerRepository.cs
```

sed replaces each line according to your command, **and puts out every line** not regarding if your substitution toke place or not.